# How to change VueRouter source file dynamicly?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Hello i have a project it contain multiple role (VueJs+Laravel), i'm using laravel as a back-end and vuejs as a front-end,
i have three diffrent role (User,Modirator,Editor).

this is my code in app.js

```
// VueRouter
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes.js';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

this is my routes file:

```
let routes = [

    // General 
    { path: '/about', component: require('./components/Home/About.vue').default },
    { path: '/pasword-change',  component: require('./components/ChangePassword.vue').default },

    // User
    { path: '/User', component: require('./components/User/Dashboard.vue').default },


    // Modirator
    { path: '/Modirator', component: require('./components/Modirator/Dashboard.vue').default },

    // Editor
    { path: '/Editor', component: require('./components/Editor/Dashboard.vue').default },


    // Error
    { path: '*', component: require('./components/Errors/404.vue').default} },

]
export default routes
```

after login i want to check it in back-end as a ajax request if the role is user use (routes-user.js) elseif is a modirator use (routes-mod.js) else (routes.js).

i dont want to show */user* */modirator* */editor* in client, but i want to check after login and each one show role component in root url */*.
thanks for help.

thanks for help....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested something similar to your requirement for normal component passing and lazy loading component in Vuex and this works. Below is my code what I am trying to do is have a variable 'unauthorized' and based on which I an loading different component using javascript ternary operator or javascript template string.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Auth from './views/Auth.vue'
import Board from './views/Board.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

let unauthorized = true;

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/auth',
      name: 'authenticate',
      component: unauthorized ? Auth : Board
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import(`./views/${unauthorized ? 'Auth.vue': 'Board.vue'}`)
    }
  ]
})
```

**Specific Solution**

As per your requirement, you can store a variable('access-type') in local storage based on whether you log in as 'moderator' or 'user' or 'editor' and then fetch it in router.js file and use template string feature to conditionally change the component path.

Do let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add meta data to your routes to solve the problem and the check the meta data before you're entering a route:

```
    { path: '/about', component: require('./components/Home/About.vue').default },
    { path: '/pasword-change',  component: require('./components/ChangePassword.vue').default },

    // User
    { path: '/User', component: require('./components/User/Dashboard.vue').default, meta: {authorize: ["Admin"]} },
```

Then add the following method to you router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const { authorize } = to.meta
  // get currently logged in user (in my case it's coming from vuex)
  const currentUser = store.getters['authentication/user']

  if (!currentUser && to.path !== '/login') {
    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    return next({ path: '/login', query: { returnUrl: to.path } })
  }

  if (authorize) {
    // check if route is restricted by role
    if (authorize.length && !authorize.some(r => currentUser.roles.includes(r))) {
      // role not authorised so redirect to home page
      return next({ path: '/' })
    }
  }

  next()
})
```